# Error in constrOptim, initial value not in the interior of the feasible region

Tags: r

I am using constrOptim to solve a portfolio problem (i.e. maximizing a quadratic function). I am reporting below the code I am using, where matrix 'Data' contains the time series of the returns of 5 assets, 107 observations each. I have already used the same codes for the optimization of a portfolio of 4 assets, and it was working well, but as soon as I add the 5th asset in the Data matrix, i got the error:

```
Error in constrOptim(guess, EQuad, NULL, ui = C, ci = D) : 
  initial value is not in the interior of the feasible region
```

Code:

```
A<- rbind(c(1,1,1,1,1), c(-1,-1,-1,-1,-1))
B<- c(0.9999,-0.9999)
C<- rbind(A, c(1,0,0,0,0), c(0,1,0,0,0), c(0,0,1,0,0), c(0,0,0,1,0), c(0,0,0,0,1))
D<- c(0.9999,-0.9999,0,0,0,0,0)

guess<- c(0.20,0.20,0.20,0.20,0.19)

Q<- rbind(c(0,0,0,0,0,0),c(0,0,0,0,0,0))
P<- rbind(c(0,0,0,0,0,0),c(0,0,0,0,0,0))

j<- 61


repeat{

  X<- data.matrix(Data)
  X<- X[1:j,]



  optm<- constrOptim(guess, EQuad,NULL, ui = C, ci = D)

  P<- rbind(P, array(unlist(optm), dim = 6))

  j <- j+1

  if(j==108){

    break

  }
}
```

My understanding is that error is caused at 'guess' vector level but also changing the initial values I still get the error.

How can I fix it?